# Remove disambiguation when citing both original and modern editions in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

At a couple of places in my bibliography, I cite an original work and a modern edition. The `date` for the old edition is the same as the `origdate` for the new edition. That shows up in the bibliography as:

> Hume, David. (1748a) 2007. An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding.
>   Edited by Peter F. Millican. Oxford: Oxford University Press.
>   ---. 1748b. An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding. London: A. Millar.

But that's not quite what I want --- I'd like to get rid of the disambiguating suffix. I'd prefer the following:

> Hume, David. 1748. An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding. London: A. Millar.
>   ---. (1748) 2007. An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding.
>   Edited by Peter F. Millican. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Is there any way to remove the suffix in such cases? (As a bonus, is there any way to have it so that the original work sorts first, as shown above?)

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
  @Book{hume48:_philos_essay_concer_human_under,
    author =       {David Hume},
    title =        {An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding},
    date =      1748,
    publisher = {A. Millar},
    location =  {London}}

  @Book{hume07:_enquir_concer_human_under,
    author =       {David Hume},
    title =        {An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding},
    date =      2007,
    origdate =     1748,
    editor =    {Peter F. Millican},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    location =  {Oxford}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no matter what settings we apply, Biber only considers one year (and one year only) for extrayear disambiguation. Which field that is can be controlled by `\DeclareLabeldate`. But that means that for extryear purposes Biber never takes into account additional year fields.

Consider a situation where you have three works by the same author

1. the first work has `date = {2000}`,
2. the second work has `date = {1960}`, and
3. the third work has `origdate = {1960}` and `date = {2000}`.

No matter what you do, in this situation you will end up with an extrayear disambiguation. If `origdate` is preferred to `date` in `\DeclareLabeldate` you will get

> 2000, 1960a, (1960b) 2000

for the three works.

If `date` is preferred you get

> 2000a, 1960, (1960) 2000b

This means that with current features we will have to resort to tricks in order to get

> 2000, 1960, (1960) 2000

which is technically not ambiguous, but bordering on ambiguous, so I would urge you to accept what `biblatex-chicago` produces by default.

---

Since Biber assigns the extrayear, we have to find a way to tell Biber not to assign extrayear in this case. David Purton's solution of clearing the extrayear field works in this case, but as he noted in general one might run into trouble, if there is another work by Hume from 1748.

A different way that will work as long there is no second work with `date = 2007, origdate = 1748,` (so logically that event should be more likely then the event that there is a second work from 1748) is to make Biber ignore the work in question for extrayear purposes with `options = {skiplab}`.

```
@book{hume07:_enquir_concer_human_under,
  author    = {David Hume},
  title     = {An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding},
  date      = 2007,
  origdate  = 1748,
  editor    = {Peter F. Millican},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  location  = {Oxford},
  options   = {skiplab},
}
```

In the MWE then your entries even sort as expected, though that is not guaranteed in all settings, so you might have to resort to `sortyear` as explained by David in his answer.

Comment: Nice. I didn't realise `skiplab` would have this effect. This is a better answer.

Comment: @DavidPurton I was lucky to have used `skiplab` just a few days ago and I feared it would do more that I wanted it to, but that fear turned out to be unsubstantiated. The answer is only marginally 'better' though, since it too will fail as soon as we have more entries with a similar date profile.

Comment: Nice! It sounds like preferring `date` to `origdate` is the best option. I'm running into a strange problem, though: if I compile my MWE with `\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date} \field{origdate}}` in the preamble, the dates come out as `1748` and `(2007) 2007`. If I use `\DeclareLabeldate{\field{origdate} \field{date}}`, things come out as expected (`1748a` and `(1748b) 2007`). Any ideas?

Comment: @arapede `biblatex-chicago` with `cmsdate=both` doesn't seem to be cut out for `\DeclareLabeldate{\field{date} \field{origdate}}`. There is a lot of special things going on when it comes to `date` and `origdate` in `biblatex-chicago`, you can't just switch without modifying *lots* of other code. The first part of the answer was mainly meant to explain why things don't work as expected, it was not mean to give an answer. You could try `cmsdate=off`, though.

Comment: Ah, got it --- I'll go with `skiplab`. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that clears the `extrayear` field when you specify in the bib entry. It doesn't change the `extrayear` field though.

Therefore, this is not quite a perfect answer because it would give potentially wrong output if you had *another* work by Hume also published in 1748. As the `extrayear` field is created by `biber`, I don't know how to deal with this.

With that in mind, this is possibly a fairly rare occurrence, so give this a go.

You can control the order using the `sortyear` field.

I remove the `extrayear` field with a new entry option (`useextrayear=false`) which is checked at every citation and bibliography entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,cmsdate=both]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
  @Book{hume48:_philos_essay_concer_human_under,
    author =       {David Hume},
    title =        {An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding},
    date =      1748,
    publisher = {A. Millar},
    location =  {London},
    sortyear = {1748a},
    options = {useextrayear=false}
    }

  @Book{hume07:_enquir_concer_human_under,
    author =       {David Hume},
    title =        {An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding},
    date =      2007,
    origdate =     1748,
    editor =    {Peter F. Millican},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    location =  {Oxford},
    sortyear = {1748b},
    options = {useextrayear=false}
    }
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{blx@useextrayear}
\toggletrue{blx@useextrayear}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{useextrayear}[true]{%
  \settoggle{blx@useextrayear}{#1}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iftoggle{blx@useextrayear}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iftoggle{blx@useextrayear}{}{\clearfield{extrayear}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\autocite{hume07:_enquir_concer_human_under}

\autocite{hume48:_philos_essay_concer_human_under}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]